# Xpage dynamic Id for data update or validation(CSJS)

Tags: xpages

Before describing the problem, I would like to add that I have looked for this problem on google and have found many solutions but none related to **XPAGES**. Since, Xpage have a unique method to generate the field id I am facing this problem. I have also posted the same question here on IBM forum and awaiting the reply there(http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ndseforum.nsf/xpTopicThread.xsp?documentId=EDEBB14BDF2E804F85257BE8001E4F76):

Problem:

I am trying to pass dynamic id to the default function getElementById with no success. To explain it clearly, I have a front end validation for specific fields. This fields are stored n database. So, I have a for loop running for all the fields. The problem here is that XPages generates the Id dynamically and hence for the same form if there is a hierarchical tabbed panel then the Id also included the tabbed panel Id in it.

Here is the code view of the problem:

The standard method to retrieve the value(CSJS) is:

***document.getElementById("#{id:inputText1}").value;***

However, if I try to pass in a dynamic  id. It doesn't work. I have tried "n" number of approaches I found on Google but none regarding this problem. One solution I tried here was:

***var x = "inputText1";***

***document.getElementById("#{id:"+x+"}").value;***

Any help would really  be appreciated. Really eager to hear some good suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"#{id:inputText1}"` part is computed at the server before the page is served so it's too late to set the ID in client side JS.

To set the ID in SSJS you can do this:

```
document.getElementById("#{javascript:var x='inputText1'; getClientId(x)}").value;
```

With `getClientId` you can also build a CSJS array of IDs in in SSJS. Then you can loop that array in CSJS. You would build the array this way:

```
var strIDs = ${javascript:'["a","b","c"]'};
```

Comment: Great, this definitely works for the above mentioned query. Thank you. However, as mentioned above: All the field names are stored in a database. So, the problem is that I can not define var x = "inputText1". It would be something like this:                        for (var i = 0; i < mandatoryFields.length; i++) {
var val = document.getElementById("#{javascript:var x=mandatoryFields[i]; getClientId(x)}").value;
alert(val);
}

Comment: Forgot to add: the above code mentioned would not identify mandatoryFields. It would throw an null pointer exception right away.

Comment: Build a CSJS array of IDs in a loop in SSJS. Then loop that array in CSJS.

Comment: Sounds great. Thank you so much..Let me try on this and keep you posted..!

Comment: Can't figure it out. Can you please post a sample code for this or rectify this sample code:    var mandatoryField = "inputText1";
    var val = document.getElementById("#{javascript:var x=mandatoryField; getClientId(x)}").value;
    alert(val);

Comment: Sorry, my sample code was wrong. However, here, I would like to know how to build CSJS array of IDs in in SSJS. Would be really helpful if you can provide a sample code.

Comment: I added a simple sample to my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am able to make it work now. To add 1 more question to same problem: I am able to call server side script in the client side script using the above mentioned method. However, the method doesn't work for external javascript. To make it more clear below mentioned code works well. However, when I put it in external script it doesn't work.    function validateFields2()
{
 var tempmandatoryFields = document.getElementById("#{id:mandatoryField}").value;
alert(tempmandatoryFields);
}
return validateFields2();

Comment: For this to work the CSJS has to be on the XPage. SSJS cannot be evaluated on external CSJS (it's just a script file and has no clue of any XPage or SSJS).

Comment: Define your CSJS functions such that they can be passed a client-side ID on which to act, e.g. `function2(targetId)`. Then you can call the function from an event or script block and pass it the resolved client ID.